using Delphi 11.3 to store data in SQLite table
I use these Delphi statements to store data in a SQLite table :
FDQry.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO Test (Var1, Var2) VALUES (1, "$£¥€")';
FDQry.ExecSQL;

Then the SQLite table Test shows : Var2 = '$£¥€'
But a Delphi DBMemo shows : Var2 = '$Â£Â¥â‚¬'
What am I doing wrong ?

How do you connect to the database?
If you use Firedac, please check the 'params.StringFormat' property in yor FDConnection component

Thanks .
The value of 'params.StringFormat' is 'sfUnicode' .

The result is exactly the same when the value is 'sfANSI' .

Do you use the same FDConnection object  for the INSERT statement and for the DBMemo? I've made a test project with Delphi12 and it's working fine.

Yes . INSERT : FDQryInsert -> FDConnection1 . And SELECT : DBMemo -> DataSource1  -> FDQrySelect -> FDConnection1
